# GPRS antenna for bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth

Can I use an external GPRS antenna for my bluetooth device to extend range area of bluetooth? I have a [Bleugiga WT11](http://www.bluegiga.com/WT11i_Class_1_Bluetooth_Module) bluetooth device.

Answer (score 2):

Two parameter of antenna which are important are

1. Frequency range
2. Impedance

Frequency range of antenna which is shown with antenna's frequency present center frequency of antenna and it's bandwidth and Impedance which is used for preventing losses of traveling  wave travels through the device and antenna. Your Bluetooth modules run in 2 GHz band and GPRS is used in 900 MHz and sometimes 1800 MHz. GPRS antenna is modified for these frequency and it will has low gain in 2 GHz. Also it is hard to match impedance for 2 GHz. So, it is not suitable to use for Bluetooth. But i recommend see antenna specification and your Bluetooth band. If your antenna has gain in Bluetooth band with considering impedance it could be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a need closer look on external antennas then you will find two port antennas with two cables and connectors. One is for cellular (GPRS) and the other is for 2400 MHz (Bluetooth / Wi-Fi). You also can get single port antennas for 2400 MHz oder only.